# Given $(c -x) % (n - 1) == 0$ for some $x$, how do I find a suitable $x$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Given $(c - x)$ $mod$ $(n - 1)$ $= 0$ for some $x$, how do I find a suitable $x$?

$c$  = constant
$x \ge 2$

$n - 1$ = constant

Comment: Can you solve the equation $c-x=0$? This is very similar.

Comment: x=c + (n - 1)*k works for every k

Comment: Use `\bmod` for the binary modulo operation.

Answer (score 0):

This is what  could make out from your question (it's a little unclear).Please let me know if I am misinterpreting somewhere.

> $(c-x)\pmod{(n-1)}=0$
>
> $\implies(c-x)\equiv0\pmod {(n-1)}$

Thus,$(n-1)k=c-x$ which implies,$x=c-(n-1)k$ for a suitable $k$.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the definition:

> "$a \bmod m = b$" means "$b$ is remainder when $a$ is divided by $m$".

Equivalently, $0 \le b < m$ and $a = km+b$ for some integer $k$.

Now just apply this to your original question and you can easily find $x$.

Comment: Note that binary modulo is common in programming and cryptography, but in other areas of mathematics the most common notation is the equivalence modulo relation where "$a \equiv b \pmod{m}$" denotes "$m \mid a-b$, which is related to the binary modulo in that it is equivalent to "$a \bmod m = b \bmod m$".